# How to make use of multiple threads in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cluster-computing

I am building an application using NodeJs and in a particular feature, I need to do aggregate and update for nearly 4000 documents in MongoDB.I Made use of promises to achieve concurrency as each promise will do aggregation and then update. my problem is every promise runs on only a single thread. is it possible to make use of cluster, so that each core will run 1000 promises in it?
I am new to this clustering technique. So any basic suggestion about it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`pm2` is great for clustering since its doing the same thing under the hood,perhaps give it a look
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/ 
and this article provides a brief intro as well
https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/clustering-in-nodejs-utilizing-multiple-processor-cores-75d78aeb0f4f

Comment: This option is creating a process and not a thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use child process

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Ref:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `worker_thread` module to create threads in Node.js. 
Each worker thread instance is really new instance of the event loop. Creating a new worker thread effectively gives a new event loop.

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');

if (isMainThread) {
    console.log('Starting the main thread');

    const worker = new Worker(__filename);

    worker.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log(`Worker: ${msg}`);
    });

    console.log('Still in main thread');
} else {
    parentPort.postMessage('Getting started');

    wasteTime();

    parentPort.postMessage('In the middle');

    wasteTime();

    parentPort.postMessage('All done');

}

function wasteTime() {
    const end = Date.now() + 3000;
    while (Date.now() < end) { }
}
```

Note: Workers (threads) are useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations. They will not help much with I/O-intensive work. Node.js’s built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers can be.

https://medium.com/@pprathameshmore/is-it-really-node-js-single-threaded-threading-in-node-js-227177c42d5a